# NewReplacer fails to replace "\n" from the given string

Tags: string, go

I'm trying to replace `\n` from the JSON using the `NewReplacer()` but it fails to identify `\n` in JSON Key Pair.

Here's the code --

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    replacer := strings.NewReplacer("\n", "", "\r", "", "|", "-")
    fmt.Println(replacer.Replace(`"\naccessKeyId": "ASIA3ASDH34KHFXCEBBSIVT",`))
}
```

PS -- The sample string is just a part of a bigger JSON.

https://go.dev/play/p/eFDNkLQE8hY

Comment: The `\n` in the argument to `Replace` is in a raw string, it's not an actual new line, it's a *literal* backslash followed by `n`, i.e. `\n` within backticks is the same as `\\n` within double quotes. https://go.dev/play/p/7eVQHm1q8ex

Comment: In this example case that is true - is it true for the problem that OP is having as well?  OP, in case that comment wasn't clear enough, `\`"\n"\`` , is equivalent to `"\\n"` rather than the escape sequence `"\n"`.

Comment: I have used backticks to write this JSON data here. In the full program, this JSON is getting marshaled and then passed to this Function. 
Is there a way to replace this new-line char from the JSON?

Comment: Use a replacer that replaces that sequence of characters that's in the JSON, e.g. https://go.dev/play/p/tYrmmd8vNWS or https://go.dev/play/p/ieQ6RdCTBKq

Comment: @mkopriva, 
I have tried the same by escaping those double quotes but I can't do this to the whole JSON log, and there are an infinite number of JSON logs getting parsed through this.

https://go.dev/play/p/LrccSw3pq32

Comment: @mkopriva, the solution you shared works on the test data. Now gonna try it with a full working program, hope it works out there as well. :)

Comment: @mkopriva it worked for me as well, thanks for your quick reply :)

Comment: @mkopriva, it worked fine for Marshaled data but fails when the JSON is stringified. It breaks the output into the next lines.

Comment: Show the code that produces the error you speak of.

Comment: This is the Test Data(https://go.dev/play/p/R2cU-PuwiQ_7) that I'm trying to Sanitize.

This works fine on the playground but when I try with my other component and logic, it fails to Sanitize it.

Comment: Then you probably need to fix your "other component and logic" if that is what is causing the invalid result. And without a [mcve] I won't be able to help because I don't know what the "other component and logic" are.